# How to add data disk to SF VMSS?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-vm-scale-set

I'm trying to deploy service fabric with data disks, and I add data disk configuration to my deploy template

```
          "dataDisks":[{
            "lun": 1,
            "createOption": "Empty",
            "diskSizeGB": 1023
          }
        ]
```

And I got error:

```
 Activity: Write-Error
 Message: ==================
3:46:16 PM - Resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets 'inode' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "OperationNotAllowed",
    "target": "dataDisk",
    "message": "Addition of a managed disk to a VM with blob based disks is not supported."
  }
}'
```

Is it even possible? to add data disk to sf scale set? I'm looking for template example

Answer (score 0):

Change your cluster VM template definition so that it uses [Managed Disks](https://github.com/ChackDan/Service-Fabric/tree/master/ARM%20Templates/Managed%20disk%20Sample).
Then you can attach managed data disks too.